How can I solve this error : repository 'https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
sudo apt update
Hit:1 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                  
Hit:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease                      
Hit:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                        
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
3 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'


FYI messages tagged N: are informational - it's not really an error as such

Particularly you may find the answer from 2021 in the above link useful.
